# Running gmt.script

Tags: bash

I try to run a gmt-script and get the message:

`bash-3.2$ plot_scenario.gmt
bash: plot_scenario.gmt: command not found`

Does anyone know what could fix the problem?
I got a script from my supervisor, and it worked just fine on the uni Linux pc. 
I have a Mac OS.

Comment: make sure it's executable (`chmod +x`) and try `./plot_scenario.gmt`.

Comment: It worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you type text in shell, it tries to look for available [commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/132369). Here bash doesn't find any command like `plot_scenario.gmt` and outputs command not found.

The proper way to execute a file is `./filename` where `.` refers to current directory. But you need to give execution permission to file you want to run. So, following commands may help you:

```
chmod +x <filename>
./<filename>
```

Note that make sure your `pwd` is where you're file is located. Another way to run or execute file is calling the shell:

```
bash /path/to/file
```